# Create a slide to control opacity for layers

Tags: openlayers-2, transparency-opacity

I am starting with my programming skills. I m self learning so I am stuck in  this point I am trying to create a web map where charge few different layers (wms) but I would like to give functionality to them providing control with the  opacity so you can overlay two layers at same time, but I have no idea how to do it. I tried few ideas I read from here but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the tour: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to include what you have tried and what you are specifically having a problem with. Do you receive an error? Paste the error text. Do you expect different results? What is the behavior you expect vs what you are seeing? Please include code snippets of what you are having issues with.